# Distort/correct atomic resolution images so the fit into a specific surfice lattice grid

Tags: texturing, image, uv-image-editor

I was encouraged by a colleague to use blender to fit a surface lattice, which is an atomic structure of a known surface, in this case GaAs(110). Unfortunately, I'm losing my mind trying to do this, I only started using blender a week ago, so I need your help.

I have an example of an AFM (atomic force microscopy) image of single atoms. The image gets distorted and skewed (usually due to thermal drift) so we need to correct this image and distorted the image so the distances are "correct".

An original AFM image, for example, looks like this: 
[image: AFM GaAs(110) image - orange blobs are atoms, ignore the black blobs and the yellow-white blobs]

And I want to distort so all the bright orange blobs in the image (the atoms) match the blue balls of this grid:

[image: GaAs(110) Grid]

This is a very poor attempt (made in Inkscape) to fit the image. In this case I modified the grid to fit the image, not the image to fit the grid, which is what I want: 
[image: Poorly fitted Grid into GaAs image]

The idea proposed to me is to create a plane mesh where each vertice is an atom and each edge is a bond. Let's call this mesh A. The idea is to modify mesh A (maybe in UV texture?) so I position each vertice on top of the atoms on the AFM image. After moving all vertices of the mesh A into the positions of the original AFM image I (lets called the deformed mesh now mesh B), I would press some magic button which would make my mesh B go back to the size/position/dimensions of mesh A and therefore deform the applied AFM image with it, deforming it and in principle correcting it.

I've created a blender file with the plane mesh (A) which you can see here: 
[BlenderFile](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pXH5iSf0Hjpr2wtgYPetF-Fp2PsTVd7o)

I can't do the rest on my own though. :-(

So how do I do this!?

PS: I'm using blender 2.8

Comment: Instead of having users go through links just to understand your question, use the tools on the site to upload images directly.  See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png). You have better chances of getting a answers if all of the information is visible in this page.

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: I think despite being a jack of all trades there would be more suited software than Blender on the market to do this (Qgis for example is a free GIS software)... You should look into Helmert transformation, which uses reference points from an origin space to a destination space to perform an homothety on the first space : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmert_transformation Alternatively you could use the lattice modifier with low resolution and rotate the lattice's points ?